# MVC Pattern/ library for dependent object-creation interface, as needed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, nuget

Is there a pattern or recommended method using ASP.NET MVC where I could be editing one object, and need to create a related object on the fly, (which may need another object created on the fly)?  Perhaps a library/ jQuery combo package that makes this easy?

Let's say I am in a page called `JournalEntries/Edit/1234` and I realize I need to create different `Account` object for the `JournalEntry` object... and maybe that `Acount` object needed a `Vendor` object that didn't yet exist.  I wouldn't want to leave the page and lose everything that was already done, but maybe nest creation forms and pass the state to the  parent window when the object was successfully created so that the workflow would be, essentially, uninterrupted.

Does such a thing exist, or are the business requirements too vague and variable to make that a realistic creation?  Are there any pitfalls or issues I would need to worry about, building this sort of model?

Comment: I feel that this is a workflow that's too specific to your use case and hard to implement generically for a library to be available.

Comment: If you're using a JS-heavy design (for example, by building on backbone.js) this sort of thing is pretty straightforward, since everything would remain in browser memory.  If you're not, then it would not be trivial to maintain such diverse state across various postbacks/pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer here, apparently, is "no"... no such library or pattern exists at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider delegating creation of the object (and its dependencies) off to a business service, which would in turn use a unit of work and repositories to create the object in the data store. The business service would return the ID of the newly created object if it could create one successfully.

Now you can create a controller action which would invoke the business services. Your front end code can call the controller action via ajax when you need to create the dependent object.

Since above approach is un-obtrusive, your workflow will not be interrupted and you wont need any special library other than jquery

Comment: How does this help the OP requirement for creating a dynamic object schema?

Comment: @Davin; It does not create/modify schema. It would create the objects within the existing schema. From what I understood, the OP requirement was to create the supporting objects that are required by an on going UI operation. May be I have misunderstood the requirement, apologies if that is the case